# Spring-Boot RestClientTest not correctly auto-configuring MockRestServiceServer due to unbound RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

EDIT: This question is specifically pertaining to the @RestClientTest annotation introduced in spring-boot 1.4.0 which is intended to replace the factory method.

### Problem:

According to the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-rest-client) the @RestClientTest should correctly configure a MockRestServiceServer to use when testing a REST client.  However when running a test I am getting an IllegalStateException saying the MockServerRestTemplateCustomizer has not been bound to a RestTemplate.

Its worth noting that I'm using Gson for deserialization and not Jackson, hence the exclude.

Does anyone know how to correctly use this new annotation?  I haven't found any examples that require more configuration then when I have already.

Configuration:

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {JacksonAutoConfiguration.class})
public class ClientConfiguration {

...

   @Bean
   public RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder() {
       return new RestTemplateBuilder()
            .rootUri(rootUri)
            .basicAuthorization(username, password);
   }
}
```

Client:

```
@Service
public class ComponentsClientImpl implements ComponentsClient {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public ComponentsClientImpl(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        this.restTemplate = builder.build();
    }

    public ResponseDTO getComponentDetails(RequestDTO requestDTO) {
        HttpEntity<RequestDTO> entity = new HttpEntity<>(requestDTO);
        ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> response = 
              restTemplate.postForEntity("/api", entity, ResponseDTO.class);
        return response.getBody();
    }
}
```

Test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@RestClientTest(ComponentsClientImpl.class)
public class ComponentsClientTest {

    @Autowired
    private ComponentsClient client;

    @Autowired
    private MockRestServiceServer server;

    @Test
    public void getComponentDetailsWhenResultIsSuccessShouldReturnComponentDetails() throws Exception {
        server.expect(requestTo("/api"))
            .andRespond(withSuccess(getResponseJson(), APPLICATION_JSON));

        ResponseDTO response = client.getComponentDetails(requestDto);
        ResponseDTO expected = responseFromJson(getResponseJson());

        assertThat(response, is(expectedResponse));
    }
}
```

And the Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to use auto-configured MockRestServiceServer since MockServerRestTemplateCustomizer has not been bound to a RestTemplate
```

### Answer:

As per the answer below there is no need to declare a RestTemplateBuilder bean into the context as it is already provided by the spring-boot auto-configuration.

If the project is a spring-boot application (it has @SpringBootApplication annotation) this will work as intended.  In the above case however the project was a client-library and thus had no main application.

In order to ensure the RestTemplateBuilder was injected correctly in the main application context (the bean having been removed) the component scan needs a CUSTOM filter (the one used by @SpringBootApplication)

```
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = {
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = TypeExcludeFilter.class)
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have RestTemplateBuilder at two places. At ClientConfiguration class and at ComponentsClientImpl class. Spring boot 1.4.0 auto-configure a RestTemplateBuilder which can be used to create RestTemplate instances when needed. Remove below code from ClientConfiguration class and run your test.

```
 @Bean
 public RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder() {
   return new RestTemplateBuilder()
        .rootUri(rootUri)
        .basicAuthorization(username, password);
  }
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate further what you mean?  If I remove the bean instantiation how is the RestTemplateBuilder injected when used in code with the regular spring context (i.e a regular @SpringBootTest)?  This change now passes my @RestClientTest but fails everything else because there is no bean in the context.

Comment: In Spring Boot 1.4.0 application RestTemplateBuilder is available as a bean and you can simply use that.

Comment: So the key here appears to be the @SpringBootApplication annotation which provides the RestTemplateBuilder as you say.  I didn't have this in my project because I'm writing a client library which won't have the application context in its stand-alone test context.  I had to add this manually for the tests which required it whilst the RestClientTest has it provided.  Can you please add this detail to your answer to clear it up for others.  The "Builder at two places" comment is very confusing - as its not actually in two places, its provided by the autoconfiguration.

Comment: @abaghel Is there a way to make this work with an RestTemplateBuilder entry in the configuration? I need to be able to set a global RestTemplateBuilder error handler

Answer (score 12):

The `MockRestServiceServer` instance should be constructed from the static factory, using a `RestTemplate`. See [this](https://objectpartners.com/2013/01/09/rest-client-testing-with-mockrestserviceserver/) article for a detailed description of the testing process.

In your example, you can do:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@RestClientTest(ComponentsClientImpl.class)
public class ComponentsClientTest {

    @Autowired
    private ComponentsClient client;

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate template;

    private MockRestServiceServer server;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        server= MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
    }

    /*Do your test*/
}
```

Comment: This method of instantiation was used before the test enchancements introduced in spring-boot 1.4.0.  @RestClientTest was introduced to do away with that particular factory method. http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-rest-client